# Report RDLC Expression with different dataset fields

Tags: visual-studio, dataset, report, expression, rdlc

This are my `datasets`:

[image]

I need to create an `Expression` for a `tablix`, something like this:

```
=iif(Fields!Taglia1 = First(Fields!DescTagliaBase.Value, "DataSetTagliaBase"), "Red", "Green")
```

The first part of the conditional expression makes references to a `tablix` with `DataSetGrigliaMisure`. The second part refers to `DataSetTagliaBase`.

The problem is that the second part, which should refer to a `dataset` not connected to the `tablix`, is not recognized and it marks error.

Comment: Tablix can refer only to one datasource. The solution is to include relevant data from the second dataset into the first one (the one tablix is linked to)